# Using mongoose but connect to Firebase

Tags: mongoose, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm thinking about using mongoose for data modeling but the persistence layer I need to use Firebase. Is it possible to achieve that? For example override some moongose methods for data CRUD?

Answer (score 0):

A plugin is available to achieve that. Perform the following steps:

```
npm install mongoose-fire
```

Use the statements below for each model:

```
const mongoose-fire = require('mongoose-fire'); 
exampleSchema.plugin(mongoose-fire);
```

Access the events as:

```
 Model.on('create')
 Modle.on('update')
 Model.on('update:<attr>')
 Modle.on('remove')
```

Reference link: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-fire